# Linux replacing a char in a file

Tags: linux

my linux command is not working as intended. I am trying to replace the tabs in my tabs.txt file with a period using asci or a period but am not able to do so.

here is my command

```
cat tabs.txt | tr '\t' '\056'
```

tabs.txt content

```
    kasdkajhsdkj
    aksdjhaksjdhaksd
    alskdjalkjsdlasd
    aslkdjalskjdalsd
```

the output is the same even after running the command

any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: That should work fine, despite the fact you win the "useless use of `cat` award" this week :-). Are you sure the file has actual tabs in it? You can check with something like `od -xcb tabs.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would write it as:

`tr '\t' . < tabs.txt`

but if you prefer the octal input you could do this in bash (you didn't say which shell you use):

`tr '\t' $'\056' < tabs.txt`